# vsdbcmd data loss may occur, but where?

Tags: database-project, datadude, vsdbcmd

When using vsdbcmd to deploy my database:

```
vsdbcmd.exe /a:Deploy /manifest:MyDatabase.deploymanifest
```

I Get:

`SQL01268    .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 127, Line 6 Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.
    SQL01268        An error occurred while the batch was being executed.`

Which is fine, but it doesn't tell me *where* the dataloss will happen. In order to find out I have to use `<DeployToScript>True</DeployToScript>`, then load the script up to see:

`IF EXISTS (select top 1 1 from [dbo].[MyTable])
        RAISERROR ('Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss  might occur.', 16, 127) WITH NOWAIT`

Is there a way to get vsdbcmd to display this info when deploying direct to the DB without having to generate the sql first?

Thanks

Comment: I've raised a Connect feedback entry related to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678292/vs2010-database-project-deployment-rows-were-detected-error-specify-table-in-message

Comment: Thanks Tom, I've just logged in and up-voted it on the connect website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this, it's a bug (or missing feature). See Tom's comment to my question.

Answer (score -1):

For me I was needed to empty my DB before deploying SQL